# Turf.js lineIntersect() not giving intersection of lineString and feature?

Tags: leaflet, line, mapping, analysis, turf

I'm displaying some polygons in Leaflet, and using Turf JS to do some calculating.

After drawing a line between the centroids of two neighboring polygons, I want to find the intersection of the line with the boundary of one of the polygons.

[image]

My code looks something like this:

```
// Calculate the distance beteween centroid of highlighted polygon and the centroid of the neighboring polygon.
const highlight_centroid = turf.centerOfMass(highlight_feature);
const centroid = turf.centerOfMass(neighbor_feature);
const line = turf.lineString([highlight_centroid, centroid]);

// Draw line between the centroids
const leaflet_line = L.polyline([turfToLeaflet(highlight_centroid), turfToLeaflet(centroid)]).addTo(test_layer);

// Find the intersection of this line with the boundary of neighor_feature

// First, check if it intersects. Turf says TRUE, the line DOES intersect neighbor_feature
console.log(turf.booleanIntersects(line,neighbor_feature));

// But lineIntersect() returns an empty feature collection.
// There should be a point coordinate
const intersection = turf.lineIntersect(line,neighbor_feature);
console.log(intersection);
```

(There's a functioning CodePen here: https://codepen.io/Kirkman/pen/JjOxjwP)

Turf's `booleanIntersects()` method says `TRUE`, they do intersect.

But when I try to use `lineIntersect()`, Turf just returns an empty feature collection. The same occurs if I try other similar methods like `lineOverlap()` or `lineSplit()`.

Am I doing something wrong? I cannot figure out why these methods are not returning anything. The line obviously intersects the polys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems comes from the fact that `turf.centerOfMass` method returns point object. When you create line with `turf.lineString` method, specifying line coordinates with point objects, this obviously produces valid GeoJSON line, but for some reason `turf.lineIntersect` method does not interpret it correctly when doing intersection.

Solution is simply to feed bare coordinates to `turf.lineString`, so line creating code should look like this:

```
const line = turf.lineString([turf.getCoord(highlight_centroid), turf.getCoord(centroid)]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that's right. I might do `highlight_centroid.geometry.coordinates` instead.